# Updating document found in iNotes calendar view

Tags: xpages

How do I edit a document displayed in a iNotes Calendar View.

I have set up a REST Service using "calendarJsonLegacyService" towards a notes view.
I have also created a iNotes Calendar and connected this to the service.

And the calendar entries are displayed alright.

But how do I manipulate this entry in the iNotes calendar events (onOpenEntry, onRescheduleEntry)?
I have named the "var" in the REST service to 'entry'.

Please keep in mind that I'm new to the whole xPage-framework.

Feeling a bit lost here :)

/Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look of TeamRoom teamplate from openNTF or from latest version of Extension Library; there you can find logic to manipulate different evets on calendar entries.